# Spam email with my address details

Tags: privacy, email, spam, fraud, secret-sharing

I have registered domain under .xyz 123reg domain registration company. Recently I got an email from ummed.org company informing me that my SEO engine will be going to expire soon and I need to make the payment. I am pretty sure it is fake email but question is how do they have all my address details. 
Is there any way to report it somewhere to remove those data and not to spread out.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Check your website on something like [this](http://whois.domaintools.com/) - Chances are your details are in your whois record.

Comment: @JonRB Why not turn this into an answer? The public WHOIS record seems to be the correct answer here.

Comment: @Arminius I didn't think it was long enough to be a proper answer. I'll try and elaborate it a bit more into answer form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## WHOIS

It sounds like your details are in your website's WHOIS records. You can check what is in them [here](http://whois.domaintools.com/). The data stored include your name, address, e-mail, and often much more.

According to [ICANN](https://whois.icann.org/en/primer)'s [specifications](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois-accuracy):

> Until otherwise specified by a Consensus Policy, such data shall consist of the following elements as contained in Registrar's database:
>
> > 3.3.1.1 The name of the Registered Name;
> >
> > 3.3.1.2 The names of the primary nameserver and secondary nameserver(s) for the Registered Name;
> >
> > 3.3.1.3 The identity of Registrar (which may be provided through Registrar's website);
> >
> > 3.3.1.4 The original creation date of the registration;
> >
> > 3.3.1.5 The expiration date of the registration;
> >
> > 3.3.1.6 The name and postal address of the Registered Name Holder;
> >
> > 3.3.1.7 The name, postal address, e-mail address, voice telephone number, and (where available) fax number of the technical contact for the Registered Name; and
> >
> > 3.3.1.8 The name, postal address, e-mail address, voice telephone number, and (where available) fax number of the administrative contact for the Registered Name.

## Privacy

There are ways of hiding this information. [Some registrars](https://www.namepros.com/threads/what-registrars-provide-free-whois-privacy.766985/) have *whois privacy* which will replace your details with those of a company.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same question with private registration, I did have the same problem too and have received the similar phishing email. I realized that the email address masked and displayed in the whois will forward the message received to my private registered email ( I have GoDaddy ). I verified it by sending emails to that address being displayed in my whois record and figured out how they tried to scam me.